# Making diffrent customer groups for not logged in

Tags: customer

Is there any way I can differentiate customer's from different locations using groups for customers that are not logged in ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't think this is the right way to do whatever you want :-) On which basis do you want to seperate?